# Escape Velocity from Moon to escape Earth-Moon System

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, escape-velocity

So the escape velocity at Earth is roughly 11.2 km/s, but with the escape velocity of the moon it says that it is 2.38 km/s but since the moon is orbiting the Earth, wouldn't the effective escape velocity at the moon increase if escaping moon away from the Earth, in order to leave the Earth-moon system and so the escape velocity is closer to 4.38 km/s right? So it is the escape velocity of the moon plus the escape velocity of Earth at moon's orbit which is roughly 2. Is this correct?

Comment: Escape velocity at Earth **at earth surface** is 11.2 km/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest example is if we neglect the sun and all the other planets, assume the earth and moon stationary and the rocket to escape in the direction radially away from both:

[image: earth moon rocket escape velocity potential]

The combined potential is

$$\rm U=U_1+U_2=-\frac{G \ M_1}{r_1}-\frac{G \ M_2}{r_2}$$

For the escape velocity we set $\rm E_{kin}=-E_{pot}$, so $\rm v^2/2=-U$, which gives

$$\rm v= \sqrt{2 \ G \ (M_1 / r_1+M_2 / r_2)}$$

With $\rm G=6.67384{\scriptsize{E}}-11  \ m^3 kg^{-1} s^{-2}$, the moon's mass and radius $\rm M_1=7.342{\scriptsize{E}}22 \ kg$ and $\rm  r_1=1.7374{\scriptsize{E}}6 \ m$, the earth's mass $\rm M_2=5.972{\scriptsize{E}}24 \ kg$ and the distance to the earths center when standing on the far side of the moon $\rm r_2=3.844{\scriptsize{E}}8 \ m + r_1=3.861374{\scriptsize{E}}8 \ m$ we get

$$\rm v=2776 \ m/s \ \ || \ \ v=2374 \ m/s$$

in order to escape from the surface of the moon, left with the earth behind you and for comparison on the right when we neglect the earth's mass (setting $\rm M_2=0$).

If we consider the moon's rotation around the earth, have the rocket launch in an arbitrary direction, or even perform swing-by maneuvers, there might not be an analytical solution and you have to fall back to [numerical](https://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?t=67) computations.

Answer (score 0):

Now if you want to escape the moon, you only need to consider what it takes to escape the moon itself; if you later get sucked into the Earth, you still escaped the moon right? You need to take the Earth-moon system into account whenever you want to escape both the Earth and the moon. Just as if you want to escape the solar system you must take into account the sun and the other planets and planetoids, etc.

This is a difficult problem, however, as you now have three bodies in question the Earth, moon and rocket. Just how to account for all the interactions exactly is not to my knowledge known. On the other hand there are perturbative techniques that allow for one to estimate with desired accuracy the effects of multiple bodies; this is what the space agencies do when they want to figure out orbits and all that sort of stuff. Because the rocket's mass is so small in comparison to the Earth and moon, the problem may not be as difficult as I am making out to be, it is still, however, more difficult than simply beefing up the mass in the ordinary escape velocity equation.